# Is it possible to run a quartz.net job on the UI thread?

Tags: watin, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, ui-thread

I'm using Watin for browser testing, which has to run on the UI thread.

I want to schedule a job using Quartz.NET but can't work out a way to run it on the UI thread (using a WPF application)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're running watin but you could:
1. Start the scheduler from inside wherever you are running watin and then connect to it via remoting from the UI thread to schedule the job.
2. Start the scheduler as a windows service and then connect to it via remoting from the UI thread to schedule the job.
3. Write a simple console app that starts the scheduler and exposes it via remoting. Then connect to it from the UI thread to schedule your job.

Take a look at this answer I wrote up earlier with some code samples:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net/1369090#1369090). Hopefully it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Quartz.NET but the Java version gives ThreadPool interface which can be implemented to make custom threadpool implementations. I don't understand why you would want to run it in a UI thread which is already dedicated to another task.