# Web based cron for free 

Tags: asp.net, cron

Is there any free web based cron that can do scheduled jobs ....

Comment: you asked a similar question sometime back; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.mywebcron.com/

but why would you want a web based cron over a standard crontab?

Comment: Jon i want to send scheduled mails for my users and i am on shared hosting they wont allow schedulers... What is a standard crontab?

Comment: Sorry, standard crontab is simply using the Linux scheduler - see http://www.adminschoice.com/docs/crontab.htm

Comment: An alternative to store all your contacts in a database (like MySQL) and use a PHP mailer, e.g. http://pommo.org/

Comment: Jon i am using mysql with asp.net ... how can i integrate PHP mailer

Comment: If you have PHP hosting then you should be able to setup pommo fairly easily, failing that look for an ASP mass mailer script...

Answer (score 1):

You can do (for free, unless your load's very heavy) periodic cron-like "sending of mails" with Google's App Engine, with [Java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron.html) or [Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) -- but I don't know of a free service that will let you do that with asp.net (or other `.NET` code).

Comment: Thanks alex for ur valuable comment

Answer (score 0):

Here's an couple of old articles on how to implement a cron job with ASP.NET: [Simulate a Windows Service using ASP.NET to run scheduled jobs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNETService.aspx) and [Scheduled ASP.NET Task (ASP.NET Cron Jobs)](http://blog.apterainc.com/software/dotnet/scheduled-aspnet-task-aspnet-cron-jobs/).

You basically just add something to the cache, and when the item expire you can use that event to trigger your code. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [www.thecloudblocks.com](http://www.thecloudblocks.com) which includes a web UI and RESTful API

Comment: DISCLAIMER: I'm the founder of CloudBlocks