# The most reliable way to schedule a job in ASP.Net 4

Tags: scheduled-tasks, asp.net-4.0

We need a practical way (not just in theory) to start a job in asp.net in a given time or in intervals.
the job could be to run a web service, a certain function or executing a page.

is there any *new* approach in ASP.Net 4 to do this?
or is there any reliable way other than using windows schedule tasks when using a shared hosting environment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

> Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net) thread on SO describes how to use it in Asp.net: [How to use Quartz.net with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting company prevents you from running Windows Scheduler on the server, use any of online task schedule services that make HTTP requests to any of your pages on the schedule that you set.