# Use one windows service to execute jobs and two web applications to schedule jobs

Tags: windows-services, quartz.net

I have one SQL Server database as the job store, two web applications that both can schedule jobs, and a Quartz.NET windows service to execute jobs.

I want the two web applications to just schedule jobs, while the windows service just to execute jobs.

**Here comes the problem:**

If I create IScheduler instances in the two web applications and in the windows service, they will execute jobs at the same time, there can be conflicts.

If I do not create IScheduler instances in the two web applications, how can I schedule jobs to the windows service from web applications?

Is there a way to let the IScheduler to just schedule jobs without executing jobs? (I can deploy the IJob assemblies to all these three applications)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably don't want to instantiate an IScheduler instance in the websites, precisely because creating a local instance also executes jobs.

I've implemented something similar to what you're looking to do.

First, make sure that in your service configuration file (app.config) that you configure the four keys `quartz.scheduler.exporter.type`, `quartz.scheduler.exporter.port`, `quartz.scheduler.exporter.bindName`, and `quartz.scheduler.exporter.channelType`.

Second, make sure that your web.config has the following four keys configured : `quartz.scheduler.instanceName`, `quartz.scheduler.instanceId`, `quartz.scheduler.proxy`, and `quartz.scheduler.proxy.address`.

Then when you create your `StdSchedulerFactory()` and use it to get a scheduler, you are not instantiating a new scheduler, but attaching to an existing scheduler.  You can then do anything through the remote scheduler that you could do with a local one, but there is only a single instance that executes jobs.

Comment: Ah, sorry, forgot to mark this the answer. This is what I want, thanks!

Comment: @Thierry It works debug mode, but not works on IIS Server due to recycling problem (only works until application pool recycle). Any idea?

Comment: If you are having a problem because of the recycle then you are still creating a local instance somehow.  You need to create an instance as a service outside of IIS then connect to it from IIS.

Answer (score 1):

In your config file, set key "quartz.threadPool.type" to "Quartz.Simpl.ZeroSizeThreadPool, Quartz". The quartz scheduler thus created can schedule/modify jobs/trigger/calendars but can not run the jobs.