# Periodically run an event on Server side itself

Tags: asp.net, events

I want to run an event periodically on the server side that is to be initiated by the server in ASP.NET scenario. There will be no request from client.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you evaluate the answers here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the server and can install external applications, you could create a stand-alone [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=VS.100).aspx) or even a console application that is triggered by the built in [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756979.aspx).

For something that runs in Asp.Net you could use [Quartz.net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/index.html). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net) SO question explains how to use it with Asp.Net

Answer (score 0):

You need to spawn a process using the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class. The process will sleep until the recurrence time comes.

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "foo";
p.Start();
```

Another alternative is to spool a thread using the [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx) class.

Comment: I would not spawn Process from the ASP.NET pool. I heard that could cause issues.

Comment: @Remy Sure it can, but on the other hand it's sometimes necessary (it really depends what the OP needs to do).

Comment: Right. But I guess it's important to note that this is not the "recommended" way.

Comment: Is this process spawned when the App is down in IIS? Or restarted (started again?)

Answer (score 0):

For a similar situation in some of the applications, I use a separate service (windows service/web service) and use `System.Threading.Timer` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) and implement a scheduler of my own. Or otherwise, you can use any server based standard scheduler to invoke some executable that in turn hits your service.

Comment: webservice + timer + scheduling. if say, my application on the server goes offline becuase of no activity on the application. Will the above combinations still be alive to hit the pending job?

Comment: A Win/web service won't go offline due to no-activity.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create a standard command line executable and have it run with the Windows Scheduling Tool. 
A windows service is fine if it runs in very short intervals, but for example for once a day task, I think its the wrong approach.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd980559)

That framework is built for this kind of things, like state persistance etc. It also runs separate, so the process will not go down when your app(pool) goes down (by default due to IIS).

Integrates fully with asp.net and you'll probably end up (in a positive way) with a [Delay Activity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.delayactivity.aspx).