# How We Can Fire Query On Specific Time Like Triegger

Tags: asp.net

How It Possible  Unpublished Record On Base Specific Time Like 22-03-2011 11:01 Pm All Record 
Are Unpublished It Is Possible From Sql Server Side.

Please Give Suggestion if it possible from

Answer (score 0):

This type of task is better served with a [Windows Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k985bc9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [Scheduled Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep your code in your ASP.NET application, place it in a page or handler and then create a scheduled task to call that URL, using, for example, [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)

Another option would be to look at something like [Quartz.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net)