# Timer on Website to activate Web Service calls every hour

Tags: asp.net, web-services, timer

If I want to run a series of Web service calls every hour. How can I do that from my Web Server?

I'm guessing there is a timer which needs to be deployed somewhere so it counts down and when the time is up, it would consume those Web service again and retrieve the returned XML data to be stored in database. Then the timer resets again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this from within an ASP.NET web application, check out the [Quartz.NET Job Scheduler](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/), it's perfect for this sort of thing.

Otherwise you could run a separate application as Windows Service with a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx), or a console application as a Windows scheduled task.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm looking at making changes to Global.asax since the Web site is on a shared hosting environment. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net

Comment: Hi again, how do I prevent this from happening? http://forums.asp.net/p/1520519/3652545.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) class with application Start event in global.asax:

```
protected static Timer timer;

protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer = new Timer(MyRoutineToCall, null, TimeSpan.FromHours(1), TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
}

protected void MyRoutineToCall(Object state)
{
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I also came across this one. Why would cache be used here? http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet.

Comment: @Jason, maybe because that's one of the ways to use Tasks. Though I don't know why Jeff would do that instead of creating a task manually. Probably my guess is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use cron?  Cron is set up to do just this sort of thing.

Comment: I'm not sure whether Cron is available with windows hosting. Correcting if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Task Scheduler may be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use an IIS Auto-Start website contaning your Windows Service logic. The IIS Auto-start is supierior to using a Windows Service as it contains all the IIS application hosting logic including auto-restart, and aggressive resource management. A poorly written Windows Service can take down a Server but it takes a lot for an ASP.net IIS hosted application to take down its host (its almost impossible).

[Auto Starting Websites](http://www.schwammysays.net/auto-starting-websites-on-iis-7-5/)