# WebService to execute every 5 minutes (on timer)

Tags: asp.net, web-services, timer

I receive a data from client on every 5 minutes i have to run my webservice on every 5 minutes so that i get that data and keep my database hot. Is it possible to run webservice on timer.
If yes, Please explain how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to read about Cache storing technique. It's really simple and works very well.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

If you mean to use Timer class, it doesn't work so well.

Also check this question,I think it's similar to yours: [Timer on Website to activate Web Service calls every hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008475/timer-on-website-to-activate-web-service-calls-every-hour)