# Asp.net mvc processing a task asynchronously

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I am working on asp.net mvc application that has one of the requirement as below.

Scenario : User submits a request to process long running task. The task will have to be initiated on the server side. And without waiting for the task to get completed, a response has to be sent to the user saying that once the task gets completed , they will get an email notification.

This seems to be a scenario for asynchronous processing. Initially I thought of using asynchronous delegates but came to know that asynchronous delegate will run as background thread and will not stay alive if the main thread exits.For me it seems , once the response is sent to the user, the main thread exits and so as background thread. Correct me if I am wrong on this.

So I thought of creating a foreground thread using Thread class. But in one of the articles I have read,it is mentioned that asp.net will not look at whether its a foreground thread or not and will not be useful. Is it true?

I am currently looking at the following atlernatives . Please suggest

1. Moving out the task processing logic outside of asp.net and put in console app/service
   and notify the app by pushing message from asp.net to MSMQ. Once the message is   received,the console app will do the processing and send an email notification
2. A WCF service to receive the message and do the processing

Any other better ideas please share

Thanks,

Sveerap

Comment: I didn't know that but any of the 2 solutions seem fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o =>
                                    {
                                        // do something aync
                                    });
```

[Previous comments on this:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250612/in-asp-net-mvc-how-can-i-run-an-expensive-operation-without-slowing-down-user-ex/7271537#7271537)

> There are lots of arguments about starving the thread request pool by
>   doing this (which is true), but the counter argument is you should
>   starve the pool because the server is busy doing work. Of course
>   ideally you should move the work off onto another server entirely via
>   queuing/distributed systems etc, but that's a complex solution. Unless
>   you need to handle hundreds of request you do not need to consider
>   this option, as it'a unlikely it would ever cause an issue. It really
>   depends of the scalability requirements of your solution, how long the
>   background process is going to take, and how often it is called.

Comment: I think ThreadPool.QueueuserWorkItem creates a background thread and since background threads cease to exist once the main thread is done, will it not create problem in the above scenario?

Comment: No it definitely won't, it will create a new thread from the thread pool and the request thread can terminate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can we say that thread will not get terminated at all when the threadpool threads are background