# Creating a job with Quartz.Net

Tags: asp.net, quartz-scheduler

I am following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356789/quartz-net-with-asp-net). I have downloaded the latest `Quartz.dll` and it is referenced in my project. I have no issues with the first part of the code (the service part) but it can't find `JobDetail`, `SimpleJob` and `CronTrigger` (the job part of the answer above).

Comment: "it can't find" Are you getting a compilation error or runtime error?

Answer (score 0):

Things you might check if you get a compilation error:

- Do you have a mismatch in .NET versions?
- Does the referred assemblies require a full .NET profile (and you only have a client profile)?
- Does the referred assemblies build target type match your code? (For example, are they build for 32bit only, and you target 64bit only)