# How to manually trigger quartz.net server job?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have Quartz.Net server running as a Windows Service. I have custom job in DLL file and everything is working. Job is triggered at night, but sometimes I need to trigger this job manually from other applications running on the same machine.

How do you trigger it?

Comment: I didn't tested it yet, but I think it answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1356789/5549917

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create an console application based on your service and in the Main add following code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestService = new  TestService ();

    #if DEBUG
        TestService.StartWork();
    #else
        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(TestService ); 
    #endif
}
```

So you can create service based on this code and in order to trigger this job just to run this console app.

Comment: I can't do that. It is a long-running job, probably longer then triggering application life. I need to find some way to communicate with server to trigger the job. But I can't find any examples.